# HP HDX 16 1200CTO laptop power cuts in and out (charging cuts in and out)

Tags: windows-7, laptop, power, charger

I have an HP HDX 16 1200CTO laptop that has been having a problem for quite sometime.  The charger cuts in and out when I'm using the computer; however, it does not when the computer is asleep, off, or hibernating.  The computer will not run on A/C power alone (will for like 5 minutes and then the computer will shut off from losing power).

I have tried a different charger, have tested my charger, and I have had geeksquad look at it.  I'm not sure where else to look.  Also, the D/C jack seems to be fine.  If it is the motherboard....what would be wrong??  Thanks!

OS = Windows 7 - 64 bit

Answer (score 1):

Unplug the battery and see if the charger will stay on. (Don't do this while running windows, use a linux live CD so you don't risk corrupting your drive.) If it doesn't power off then your battery is duff. If it powers off then that leaves the power socket, the charger circuit and/or the motherboard. in which case, unless you are proficient in electronics, it's a professional repair job.